# Refactoring package name and renaming applicationID still gives gradle fail

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had to rename my package which I did accordingly to what I've seen on here. I changed the applicationId to the same package name. However when I go to sync my gradles or even clean the project I get a "No matching client for package" but it's changed everywhere as I did refactor->rename and checked everywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share error log for more information

Comment: same as @MarkLoke and btw, you renamed gradle, manifest and all packages with refactor?

Comment: Make sure package name is also updated in Manifest. `package="your.new.packagename"`

Comment: follow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package) it worked for me. it might help you

Comment: @xbadal I used the accepted answer there and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To all the commenters I figured it out. It was my `google-services.json` file that I didn't change the package name in.

Sorry to have wasted your time but thanks for the responses!